# Axios get request to Laravel endpoint from next.js

Tags: laravel, axios, next.js

I have the following request to my laravel endpoint:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/auth/login', {})
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return {};
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                return {}
            });
```

And my laravel endpoint set up as:

```
public function index() {
        var_dump('login called.');die;
        return response()->json(
            [],
            200
        );
    }
```

I Started my nextjs server (port 3000) and laravel server(8000), and when i browse to localhost:8000/auth/login in my browser I see "login called". however when I do that axios call, I get a status 200ok but no response data.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/auth/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes `die;` is wrong

Comment: ahh you are right, i thought minimum the var_dump shoud have been returned. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code you are getting the response correctly, you see "login called" because you are accessing from a browser, therefore a browser has the cappability to render the html and you can see that.

But that axios call expects some json in return.
If you tweak the response a bit:

```
public function index() {

        return response()->json(
            ['data' =>'Log in called'],
            200
        );
    }
```

and if you twak axios response a bit

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/auth/login', {})
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                return {};
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                return {}
            });
```

Inspect element open console and you will see `'Log in called'`